# Solving a Convolution Problem

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

I was unable to solve a convolution question.Question is attached herewith.[image]

I don't know how to initiate for solving the problem and what is the final expression that prove the convolution of  a top-hat function with itself is the triangle function.

Comment: Hi! you may initiate by writing down the convolution integral, and the piecewise defintion of your "top-hat" function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you slide a rectangular signal over another rectangular signal and take the area under the curve, i.e., perform convolution, at first there is no overlap. Then, the overlap gradually starts increasing in a linear fashion. When the two rectangular signals are exactly on top of each other, that is the point of maximum overlap. After than, there is a gradual decrease until there is no overlap. The resulting convolution signal is then a triangular signal.

**Update:** A rectangular signal is given by
\begin{equation*}
\prod (t) =
            \begin{cases}
1 &  0 \le t \le 1 \\
0 & otherwise
            \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
Its convolution is given by
$$z(t) = \int _{\tau=-\infty}^{\infty} \prod(\tau) * \prod(t-\tau) d\tau$$
which turns out to be
\begin{equation}
z(t) = \begin{cases}
0 & -\infty \le t \le 0 \\
t & 0 \le t \le 1 \\
2 - t & 1 \le t \le 2 \\
0 & 2 \le t \le \infty
\end{cases}
= \Lambda(t)
\end{equation}

Comment: Can you please  show solution mathematically?

Comment: Just did above.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't know what is top hat function.
But, I know convolving rectangular function with itself will result in triangular function.

The below image illustrates more, what hidden meaning in the equation you need to prove.
[image]